# Algebraic varieties and irreducibility

Tags: algebraic-geometry

When I was reading some references I found out a conflict in the definition of an algebraic variety, one defines this notion to be irreducible and other does not
Can I have a clear definition and why suppose that the variety is not neces irreducible?
Thank you

Comment: Just like some people only consider them so when the field is algebraically closed. The larger the population using a language the more small variations in the semantic you will find.

Comment: Ah, your concrete question: Solutions of polynomial equations, which is what algebraic varieties are (or generalize) can come from polynomials that factor: $xy=0$. Then the zero set is the union of the sets $x=0$ and $y=0$ (closed in the Zariski topology). If the scope of interest of your study cares about those cases, you include them to limit the amount of words you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have always considered varieties to be irreducible over algebraically closed fields since we have tools like the Nullstellensatz at our disposal, and thus objects like coordinate rings are much nicer to evaluate in this case.  In arbitrary fields, we may not have a Nullstellensatz, so there might not be much to gain by considering irreducible algebraic sets.